# Including many interaction terms in a logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, model, regression-strategies

I have a logistic regression model that is currently of the form:

```
Event ~ Vacc + Age
```

I want to start including interaction terms for different types of vaccine.  I have been able to do:

```
Event ~ Vacc + Age + Vacc*VaccRoute
```

Where `VaccRoute = 0` for intramuscular and  `= 1` for intranasal.  This gives me nice results.

Now I want to look at the effect of vaccine brand.  There are approximately 20 different vaccine brands in my data.  I have made dummy variables for them all.

My question is, do I model this as A or as B?

A, i.e. a single model

```
Event ~ Vacc + Age + Vacc*Brand1 + Vacc*Brand2... + Vacc*Brand20
```

B, i.e. multiple runs of the model changing the interaction term each time

```
Event ~ Vacc + Age + Vacc*Brand1
Event ~ Vacc + Age + Vacc*Brand2
...
Event ~ Vacc + Age + Vacc*Brand20
```

Do I "use up" statistical power more doing it one way?  Do I generate erroneous confidence intervals doing it the other?

Apologies for such a basic question but I haven't been able to find a succinct answer anywhere on CV or elsewhere.

Comment: At least you should **not** run the model 20 times with a new interaction term each time! How do you want to interpret that? But with 20 brands you get a lot of parameters ... maybe let the brand interactions be random effects, or use some form of regularization?  Some ideas here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/differences-between-regression-using-base-r-and-using-rms-package/64417#64417